# How can I make JavaScript detect when variable c changes and do something?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, compare

Lets say I have a variable that changes such as-

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('chat incoming').length;
```

How could I make the latest result of the variable `c` get compared the the last result of the variable `c`? Or my question rephrased, how can I make something happen when variable `c` changes?

No proxy please.

variable `c` is the amount of that specific element.

Edit:
If you need this code then here it is.

javascript/chat.js

```
const form = document.querySelector(".typing-area"),
incoming_id = form.querySelector(".incoming_id").value,
inputField = form.querySelector(".input-field"),
sendBtn = form.querySelector("button"),
chatBox = document.querySelector(".chat-box");

form.onsubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
};

inputField.focus();
inputField.onkeyup = ()=>{
    if(inputField.value != ""){
        sendBtn.classList.add("active");
    }else{
        sendBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }
};

sendBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/insert-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
  if(xhr.readyState !== undefined && xhr.readyState === 4){ 
      if(xhr.status === 200){
          inputField.value = "";
          var audio = new Audio("php/sounds/good_notification.mp3");
          audio.play();
          scrollToBottom();
      }
  }
};
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
};
chatBox.onmouseenter = ()=>{
    chatBox.classList.add("active");
};

chatBox.onmouseleave = ()=>{
    chatBox.classList.remove("active");
};

setInterval(() =>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/get-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            let data = xhr.response;
            chatBox.innerHTML = data;
            if(!chatBox.classList.contains("active")){
                scrollToBottom();
              }
          }
      }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("incoming_id="+incoming_id);
}, 500);

function scrollToBottom(){
    chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
  }
function NotifyNewMessage() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName('chat incoming').length;
  alert(c);
}
```

I though about using a database to store this info and have the JavaScript check to see if the latest data in the database is less then `c` and if it is then do something but I don't know how.

Edit:
This is the chat.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include_once "php/config.php";
  if(!isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
<?php include_once "header.php"; ?>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="chat-area">
      <header>
        <?php 
          $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['user_id']);
          $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `unique_id` = {$user_id}");
          if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
          }else{
            header("location: users.php");
          }
        ?>
        <a href="users.php" class="back-icon"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <img src="php/images/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" alt="">
        <div class="details">
          <span><?php echo $row['fname']. " " . $row['lname'] ?></span>
          <p><?php echo $row['status']; ?></p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="chat-box">

      </div>
      <form action="#" class="typing-area">
        <input type="text" class="incoming_id" name="incoming_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="message" class="input-field" placeholder="Type a message here..." autocomplete="off">
        <button><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="javascript/chat.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the way the variable `c` is set up it would not change automatically even if you add more nodes with class `chat-box`, because variable `c` just stores a `Number`.

If variable `c` was just this `var c = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-box');`, then it would have always been up to date according to the `chat-box` nodes in the DOM.

Now, if you want to listen to whenever the length changes, which means more nodes with class `chat-box` have been added *(same goes if you remove nodes)*. You will have this info wherever you're updating the `chat-box` DOM nodes.

In the following code snippet, I've a button that adds a `div` element with class `chat-box` into the body, and this change is also reflected by the `c` variable. So inside the click listener itself I can put other logic as well, which is suppose to run when `c` changes.

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-box');
var d = c.length;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "chat-box";
  div.innerText = "Hello World";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  d = c.length;
});
```

```html
<button>Add Chat Box</button>
<div class="chat-box">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

c is just a simple number.

Assuming what is required is to be informed when the number of elements with class chat incoming changes you could first set up a MutationObserver on the relevant container element then when that is called you look to see whether c is still equal to `document.getElementsByClassName('chat incoming').length`

MutationObserver is a bit more helpful than just noticing whether a length has changed, as it isn't just telling you that the number of chat-boxes may have changed, but even if the number is the same you still get to have a look - which you may want because there may have been an addition and a deletion, i.e. the chat has changed.

Comment: So I am doing this to add a notification feature on a website

Comment: I have the div class `chat-box` and it auto updates every .5 seconds

Comment: Hmm, not sure I'm answering the right question now, but let's have a think. How does your auto-update work/what does it do to get the new info?

Comment: @AHanworth can you look at the code I provided above?

Comment: Thanks?I can see where you overwrite chatBox with the response but I can't see where the length/number of elements with class chat might change. What have I missed? Perhaps we need to see the basic HTML structure?

Comment: Ah, it's probably that the elements with class chat are children of chatBox - sorry I'm being a bit slow!

Comment: Are you there? I kinda still need help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230900/discussion-between-a-haworth-and-javascriptisthebest).

Comment: sure thing im there

Answer (score 0):

So in chat.js you should add this at the bottom below everything.

```
function NotifyNewMessage() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName('chat incoming').length;
  var d = document.getElementById("hidden").value;
  var audio = new Audio("php/sounds/good_notification.mp3");
  if(c != d){
      audio.play();
      document.getElementById("hidden").value = c;
  }
}
```

You should also add this

```
NotifyNewMessage();
```

At this

```
setInterval(() =>{
    NotifyNewMessage();
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/get-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            let data = xhr.response;
            chatBox.innerHTML = data;
            if(!chatBox.classList.contains("active")){
                scrollToBottom();
              }
          }
      }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("incoming_id="+incoming_id);
}, 500);
```

You should put this in chat.php

```
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="0">
```

Now the only this you got to do is figure out a way to make the user interact with the document.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Proxy and than call a function when the object changes. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: I will check that out

Comment: I'm not so good with proxy, I rather not get into that. Is there some other way?

Comment: don't get it either. The `.length` property is not really a property (like a HTMLCollection is not an array), so it's value is never "set"? How does a Proxy help then?